# Xamarin FCM not working while app is closed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase cloud messaging for remote notification in Xamarin Android, the notification are working fine while the app is in foreground and in background but if the app is closed the notification do not arrive.

I followed step by step the [Xamarin tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vswin).

Any idea?

Comment: The problem happens when you are debugging with visual studio ?

Comment: Yes, I have not tried in release mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem happeds because VS literally kills your app, so the background proccess that listens for push notifications die, so it will no longer respond. What you have to do for test push notifications is debug and  reinstall de app every single time.

Best Regards.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with debug and reinstall? To run the app with VS on debug mode and then what? Or am I completely lost? Sorry for my nescience.

Comment: I mean, when you are debugging and then stops depuration, you must reinstall the app.this is only when you are developing the app, in release mode and normal installation this won't occurs